# Modeling two variable non-linear regression

Tags: r, nonlinear-regression

I would like to fit a model to the data set that has two predictors, wind and relative humidity, and the response is inoculum production. The response to increasing in RH is sigmoid. I am not really sure how to approach this. I do not know how to fit a non-linear model (for example logistic) to data with multiple variables. The data comes from an old article and only means are available for each combination of factor levels.
 The data:

```
dis_df <- structure(list(rh = c(100, 95, 90, 85, 80, 100, 95, 90, 85, 80, 
100, 95, 90, 85, 80, 100, 95, 90, 85, 80), wind = c(0.3, 0.3, 
0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 
13.7, 13.7, 13.7, 13.7, 13.7), spor = c(66927, 83117, 76360, 
17542, 7857, 95804, 98221, 17147, 4384, 69, 90982, 7741, 179, 
93, 185, 139531, 4887, 292, 417, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Some visualisation:

```
ggplot(spor_df, aes(factor(spor_df$wind, levels = c("0.3", "1.4", "5.5", "13.7")), rh))+
  geom_tile(aes(fill = spor))+
  xlab("Wind (m/s)")+
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "lightgray", high = "black")
```

Comment: Before you worry about fitting a model, you need to have a model. Can you provide the model equation?

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the data in e.g. a visualisation like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

dis_df <- tibble(rh = c(100, 95, 90, 85,
                        80, 100, 95, 90,
                        85, 80,100, 95,
                        90, 85, 80, 100,
                        95, 90, 85, 80),
                 wind = c(0.3, 0.3,0.3, 0.3,
                          0.3, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4,
                          1.4, 1.4, 5.5, 5.5,
                          5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 13.7,
                          13.7, 13.7, 13.7, 13.7),
                 spor = c(66927, 83117, 76360, 17542,
                          7857, 95804, 98221, 17147,
                          4384, 69, 90982, 7741,
                          179, 93, 185, 139531,
                          4887, 292, 417, 0))

dis_df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = as_factor(rh), y = spor)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = round(seq(min(dis_df$spor),
                                    max(dis_df$spor),
                                        by = 20000),1),
                     labels = scales::comma) +
  xlab("Mean Relative Humidity") +
  ylab("Mean Spore Inoculum Production") +
  facet_grid(~wind, labeller = label_both)
```

And calculate the (partial) correlations.

Comment: I did look at data in a number of ways, and this being one of them just using line plots.  Just thought this might be an interesting way to show it. I need this for inference, correlations are not really helpfull.